# How enter a correct path?

Tags: html, css, django, templates, django-templates

In the linked picture you can see the path to the css folder  ,i tried to open the server . The html code works . But the css doesn't work . I think the problem is in the path . If yes , how to correct it ? I have no idea

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="description" content="Crypto currency news">
  <meta name="keywords" content="bitcoin altcoin>
  <meta name="unknown" content="industry">
  <title>Acme News | About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
```

[image]

Comment: Use `{% static ... %}`.

Answer (score 2):

In django, you can manage static files by using `{% static %}`.

For using this, you have to set few things

1. make sure `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included in `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. Define `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py`
3. In template, use static template tag. (`{% load static %}`)
4. load your static using `{% static %}`. i.e. `{% static 'path/to/example.jpg' %}`

Django official docs well explain about this. please check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/)

Comment: but thats not an image , i want to load css ! is this the same way for css ?

Comment: Of course. That's how django manage static files - including css, js. Just add your css file in your `static` directory, (i.e. `static/css/style.css`) and call it by `{%  static 'css/style.css' %}`

Comment: For beginner, it's little bit confusing to manage static files. (especially in dev environment.) I recommend read django docs for understanding correctly.

Comment: that helped alot

Comment: html files should also be added to the static files ?

Comment: Nope, you just add your `static` files. You can check about static files here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918845/what-exactly-does-serving-static-files-mean-and-should-you-do-it).

Answer (score -1):

U should enter "../" to go to the previous folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```