# How to serve static files in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to build a small server similar to Flask and want to serve static files from it. My first thought was that [Genie.jl](https://genieframework.github.io/Genie.jl/dev/index.html) could do this but I don't see anything about [serving static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918845/what-exactly-does-serving-static-files-mean) explicitly mentioned (unless I missed it).

Comment: For the person who voted too close because this "needs more focus", how much more focus is needed? Is there another layer of specificity beyond "How to serve static files in Julia?"? Seems like a pretty straightforward and clear question in this context....

Comment: If you don't know what serving static files means, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918845/what-exactly-does-serving-static-files-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply place static file in the `public` folder of a created Genie app. If you have a peek at this folder you will even notice that Genie automatically places there standard web page files such as favicon.ico or robots.txt.

Consider the following Julia session:

```
julia> using Genie
julia> Genie.newapp("Demo1")
...

Ready!

┌ Info: 2021-10-24 02:56:09
└ Web Server starting at http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

When being started Genie automatically changed location to the web app folder (here Demo1).

Let us create a sample static file in the `Demo1/public` folder:

```
open("public/static_sample.txt","w") do f;println(f,"Hello world!");end
```

Now we are ready to test the mechanism. Here I use `curl` tool being run from Julia, but you could simply copy-paste the url to a web browser:

```
julia> run(`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/static_sample.txt`)
Hello world!
Process(`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/static_sample.txt`, ProcessExited(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to use Genie for serving static files is to use `Genie.serve` as documented here: https://genieframework.github.io/Genie.jl/dev/API/genie.html#Genie.serve

```
julia> Genie.serve("public", 8888, async = false, verbose = true)
[ Info: Ready!
[ Info: Listening on: 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Out of the box it will serve the requested file if it exists, it will return a 404 error page if it does not exist, and will look for an index.html file to serve by default if the path is a directory.

It does not list the files in the directory - though we could add it if useful, as an option.